# Append occurrence number to each element

Tags: r

Maybe the problem does not match the topic, and it is a bit difficult to describe the problem. I have a matrix like the following:

```
  V1
1 A
2 B
3 B
4 C
5 D
```

I want it to become as follows：

```
  V1
1 A_1
2 B_1
3 B_2
4 C_1
5 D_1
```

Is there any function or package that can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: You want to count the number of appearances of each element and suffix the number to it?

Comment: Yes this is what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `group_by` the variable V1 and then paste together V1 and the line number `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(V1 = paste(V1, row_number(), sep="_"))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
# Groups:   V1 [5]
  V1   
  <chr>
1 A_1  
2 B_1  
3 B_2  
4 C_1  
5 D_1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found that I don’t have a mutate function, which package should I library?

Comment: use `dplyr` package

Comment: Sorry that I did not describe my problem well. In this set of examples, I want to convert B to B_1, B_2 (meaning the first and second occurrence of the character B). How should I achieve this?

Comment: @leelee I think that's what I've done, no?

Comment: When I use this line of code I get B_2,B_2 instead of B_1,B_2

Comment: Sorry, see edit.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

you looking for this?

```
mat<-matrix(data = c("a", "b", "c"))
mat<-paste0(mat, "_", seq(mat))
as.data.frame(mat)
    
  mat
1 a_1
2 b_2
3 c_3
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base` solution:

```
 transform(df, V1 = paste0(V1, "_",ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), V1, 
                                          FUN = seq_along)
                               ))
   V1
1 A_1
2 B_1
3 B_2
4 C_1
5 D_1
```

One can also do the same with `within`.

```
within(df, {V1 = paste0(V1, "_",ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), V1, 
                                          FUN = seq_along)
                              )})
```